# Following validation example but flagging errors, has it been removed?

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin.forms, data-annotations

Tried out the validation from

```
https://github.com/davidbritch/xamarin-forms/blob/master/Validation/MVVMUtopia/Models/User.cs
```

however:

```
public class User : ValidatableBase
```

ValidatableBase only gives the option to 'Generate class or type etc'

tried adding

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

but it is flagging DataAnnotations does not exist.

Has this been removed?

Comment: https://github.com/davidbritch/xamarin-forms/blob/master/Validation/MVVMUtopia/Validation/ValidatableBase.cs

Comment: DataAnnotatons classes are in an assembly you need to reference first: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you? You can mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

The [ValidatableBase](https://github.com/davidbritch/xamarin-forms/blob/master/Validation/MVVMUtopia/Validation/ValidatableBase.cs) class is right there in the project and has not been removed.

Download the [sample project](https://github.com/davidbritch/xamarin-forms) and then import those classes you need to your test project.

To use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, you should install it first:

[image]